# Collapsing and expanding sections, image not shown

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello I have a table that may have many rows. I want to modify table appearance by adding collapsing and expanding sections on the  element. So I followed the [tutorial](http://programming4.us/mobile/3150.aspx).

The demo is at http://jsfiddle.net/zhshqzyc/3pajE/2/

I hope that the icon is sitting on the left of text "2012 Year" then I click it.
However the image doesn't show at all.

Thanks for checking the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `class="collapsible"` to your table

This `$('table.collapsible tbody')` refer to table with **collapsible** class, so the table should be:

```
<table id="myTable" width="560" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" class="collapsible">
```

Comment: Great, the default icon is bullettoggleminus. How can I change it as bullettoggleplus?

Comment: @Love you could change `collapseIcon` and `expandIcon` reference image url or add the image via CSS `$('<img width="20" height="20" />').attr('src', collapseIcon)` could be `$('<div />').addClass('myOnClass OR myOffClass')`and so on. This is an example.